# creation of xml document

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a table in my database (Mysql) which has 6 columns. I am using PHP forms to store the data in this database. One of the column is for url. I am able to store the data in the database and now I want to construct an XML document with the URL as the data.

```
Database name: probe_config
table name   : webmeasurementsuite
```

My database details are as follows:

```
url:(varchar,binary and the default value is null)
replication:(integer,unsigned,zerofill and default value is null)
wait:(integer,unsigned,zerofill and default value is null)
timeout:(integer,unsigned,zerofill and default value is null)
clearcache:(varchar,binary and default value is null)
name:(varchar,binary and default value is null)
id  :(integer,notnull,autoinc,unsigned,zerofill and default value is null)
```

Can anyone help me in converting this to xml document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get your database results as an array, you can use a function [like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#101949) to convert that array into an XML document. But do not assume such a function is best performance-wise or software design wise.

Assuming that your database connection is already done,

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url FROM webmeasurementsuite");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

foreach ($result as $v) {
    $xml .= '<url>'.htmlspecialchars($v['url'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</url>';
}
```

Comment: thanks..Shall I know how to convert the database results as an array?  Can I have an example.

Comment: thanks..I would like to know where to insert it.Should I insert it in my php coding if so where exactly to insert it.

Comment: Yes, you should put this into your PHP code.